# PHP Login Script with redirect

Tags: javascript

I don't know if any of you are familiar with the Pancake App (Self Hosted Invoicing) I am trying to make a script that allows my clients to login to their accounts from a login screen on my web page. (I think I just need a whole new script, fix after fix just provides more and more errors. :(

I have this script that I pieced together but it is returning errors:

```
    <?php
$con=mysqli_connect("example.com","exampleuser","examplepass","db_name");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM mypanda_clients
WHERE unique_id='$_POST[username]'");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  if ($_POST[password] == $ROW[password])
  {
  header('Location: http://www.green-panda.com/my_panda/Clients/$_POST[username]);
  }
  else 
  {
    echo "The username and or password was incorrect. Please try again."
  }
  }
?>
```

The error that is returning is:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';' in /home/content/38/10473938/html/website/panda/login.php on line 21
```

I am needing this script to

1. match the username with the unique_id in the database
2. Verify the password matches the unique_id
3. Forward the user to: http://www.green-panda.com/my_panda/Clients/"unique_id"

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you just update your question to remove the errors identified in the answers below? If so, please don't do that. It invalidates all of the answers and makes this question useless to future site visitors.

Comment: Is there a way to un-edit? I didn't mean to update the answer with the solution I copied and pasted and didn't realize I had.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two typos:

```
header('Location: http://www.green-panda.com/my_panda/Clients/'.$_POST[username]); // concatenate the string
```

and

```
echo "The username and or password was incorrect. Please try again."; // missing semi colon
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing `'` here i think...

```
header('Location: http://www.green-panda.com/my_panda/Clients/$_POST[username]);
```